# Is my usage of the colon in this sentence accurate?

Tags: punctuation

From what I understand, one of the functions of the colon, among other things (introducing lists, direct speech/quotation  etc), is to act as a link between two sentences. (A formal version of the dash, if you will.)

Is the usage of the colon in the following sentence good?

> It took nine days for Eugene to consume it all. For nine days, he ate
>   nothing but chimpanzee meat. Seated alone at the table in the 'open
>   room' he ate: slowly, little by little.

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is right in this sentence: semicolon or colon?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/which-is-right-in-this-sentence-semicolon-or-colon) and [can a colon be regarded as a junction for complex sentences?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/can-a-colon-be-regarded-as-a-junction-for-complex-sentences/).  What follows your colon is not a sentence, but I think the discussion is helpful. Your own sentence is fine.