# Does using a colon (:) correctly combine these 2 sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, colons

I'm asking about the following construction. I'm not sure whether the way I use a colon to combine my sentences is correct.

> Here, I would like to summarize the reasons for my extension
>   request`:` as necessity of additional time for rectifying the
>   algorithms, lengthy literature survey than expected and etc.

Comment: You can read more about colons and semi-colons in this question [Which is right in this sentence: semicolon or colon?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/which-is-right-in-this-sentence-semicolon-or-colon/1368#1368).

Comment: "Lengthy literature survey than expected" doesn't make sense. You probably mean to say "a lengthy literature survey which took more time than expected."  You also probably want to say something like "I need additional time to rectify the algorithms" instead of what you have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your sentence. The colon is only one.

> Here, I would like to summarize the reasons for my extension
>   request : as necessity of additional time for rectifying the
>   algorithms, lengthy literature survey than expected and etc.

The first problem is that there is no space **before** the colon, only after the colon.

The second is that the list of reasons is likely to be too long, which will make the sentence difficult to read and understand. I'd recommend that you use a different kind of list. For example:

> I have four *[However many there are]* reasons for requesting an extension. First, I need more time to rectify the algorithms. Second, reviewing the literature is taking much longer than I expected. Third, yada yada yada. Fourth, blah blah blah.

You can also choose to use a bulleted list instead:

> I have four reasons for requesting an extension:

- I need more time to rectify the algorithms.
- reviewing the literature is taking much longer than I expected.
- Yada yada yada.
- Blah blah blah.

Comment: Bravo! Four nominals reverbalized!

Answer (score 1):

You would use a colon or semi-colon when joining 2 independent clauses. But in your example, the second clause

> as necessity of additional time for rectifying the algorithms, lengthy literature survey than expected and etc.

refers to the reasons for *summarizing* mentioned in the first clause. Also the first clause is not independent (able to stand by itself). So you should use a comma instead.

> Here, I would like to summarize the reasons for my extension request, **due to the** necessity of additional time for rectifying the algorithms, lengthy literature survey than expected and etc.

I used *due to* because the second clause is explaining or expanding on the first clause.

Comment: I think not; *due to* in this construction would describe your reasons for *summarizing*, not for the request.

Comment: @StoneyB I read it again and agree. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Colons are used to introduce a phrase that explains what previously said, and a list.

> I like the old manga series: UFO Robot Grendizer, Mazinger Z, and Steel Jeeg.

Probably, "as necessity of additional […]" should be "the necessity of additional […]"; also "lengthy literature survey than expected" should probably be rephrased.